# Problem showing the country with the most deliveries by week

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe called df1 with three columns: Country, Week_number and Total_deliveries

Below is the output using: `df1.head(10)`

[image]

And this is the output if I select some rows using: `df1.take([1, 50, 180, 256, 147])`

[image]

I would like to be able to get the highest total delivery per country per week.

So far I tried using this code:

```
df_most_deliveries = df1.groupby(['Week_number']).agg({'Total_deliveries': ['max']})
```

And I get this result below. It is very close to what I want. I just need to add the country name.

[image]

Then when I add the country column: `df_most_deliveries = df1.groupby(['Week_number', 'Country']).agg({'Total_deliveries': ['max']})`

This is the result:

[image]

Something is not right with my code. Because it lists all the countries for each week. But I would like only one country with the highest total deliveries grouped by week number.

How could I change the code to fit this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Week_number')['Total_deliveries'].idxmax()]
```

You can also obtain this with `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values('Total_deliveries').drop_duplicates('Country', keep='last')
```